# Using Socket.io in Express.js Project

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, mean-stack

I'm making some single page web application with Node.js, Express and Socket.io. **I want to display how works are going to browser.** In IDE, There is console, so I can check program process in console window. Like, I want to show these process to browser. All I want to is just 'emit'.

When I use socket.io in `app.js` file, there is no problem. but this is limited for me. I want to display many sentences in realtime as running. How can I use socket.io in not only app.js but controller.js? I red [Use socket.io in controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559135/use-socket-io-in-controllers) this article, but I can't understand. Please help me with a simple solution.

**app.js**

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

module.exports.io = io;
...
```

**controller.js**

```
var io = require('./app').io;
// some task
console.log('Task is done!'); // it would be seen in console window
io.sockets.emit('Task is done!'); // Also I want to display it to broswer
```

**Result (error)**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined
```

---

**Edit 2---**

Follwoing **Ashley B**'s comments, I coded like this.

**controller.js**

```
module.exports.respond = function(socket_io) {
    socket_io.emit('news', 'This is message from controller');
 };
```

**app.js**

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var controller = require('./controller');
io.sockets.on('connection', controller.respond );
```

It works well, But what I wonder is... When I want to several `socket_emit`, What Should I do? Should I call everytime? If you don't understand. see below :

```
//first task is done 
module.exports.respond = function(socket_io) {
    socket_io.emit('news', 'First task is done!');
 };

//second task is done 
module.exports.respond = function(socket_io) {
    socket_io.emit('news', 'Second task is done!');
 };

//third task is done 
module.exports.respond = function(socket_io) {
    socket_io.emit('news', 'Third task is done!');
 };
```

But It is wrong way, right? only last api is implemented in `app.js`. There are a lot of `console.log` in my controller, I want to convert it to `socket.emit` How can I do this?

Comment: Something along the lines of this should work - app.js: `require('./controller.js)(io)` and then on controller.js you would do: `module.exports = function(io) { // socket stuff here// }`

Comment: @Ashley B I can't understand.... do I need call module.exports every log? I couldn't guess at 'socket stuff' what I have to input.

Comment: You could add `io.sockets.emit('Task is done!');` in there, as you used in your example.

Comment: @AshleyB Can you check addition please? Do I need call module.exports every log?

Comment: No, you'll just overwrite the previous one doing that.

Comment: @AshleyB How can I do that? I get all confused...

Comment: You would do something like: `module.exports.respond = function(socket_io) {
    socket_io.emit('news', 'First task is done!');
    socket_io.emit('news', 'Second task is done!');
 };` I suggest you read up on how exporting works in node.js

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on this using *socket.io* and *nodejs events*. The idea is to handle the emission of the socket only from the `app.js`, and emit nodejs events from controllers, which will be captured in `app.js` and then issued by the socket.

**app.js**

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const events = require('events');

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Someone has connected");
    var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
    eventEmitter.on("newEvent", (msg) => { // occurs when an event is thrown
        socket.emit("news", msg);
    });

    exports.emitter = eventEmitter; // to use the same instance
});
```

**myController.js**

```
const app = require('../app');    
.....

if (app.emitter) // Checking that the event is being received, it is only received if there is someone connected to the socket
    app.emitter.emit("newEvent", "First task is done!");    
.....

if (app.emitter)
    app.emitter.emit("newEvent", "Second task is done!");
```