# Socket.IO + Express framework | Emit/Fire From Express Controller & Router

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I need to emit the socket from the server from anywhere on server code, Router/Controller. I checked and some of the threads and Google but nothings works as expected.

**app.js**

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

require(./router.js)(app)
require(./socket.js)(io)

app.listen(80);
```

**router.js**

```
module.exports = function (app) {
app.use('/test', require(./controller.js));
return app;
};
```

**socket.js**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

**controller.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
 // I need to emit here

});

module.exports = router;
```

This is not a extract code I am using. This is an structure how I am using and where I need to call.

Comment: It does not look like your router s connected to your server instance at all.

Comment: This is an sample structure of my code. my router is connecting. Is there way to emit from controller. I will revise my code

Comment: If you just want to be able to do `io.emit()` from other modules, then just pass `io` to them in their constructor.  Or, make a method on some other module that you can retrieve the `io` variable by `require()` that module and then call a method on it to fetch `io`.

Comment: @jfriend00, I will try..

Comment: I think did we have a function io.emit() on scoket.io. I will find only io.sockets.emit(). Can we pls provide me the doc link.

Comment: Official doc is not deep enough http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: `io.emit()` sends to all connected sockets.  Doc is [here](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit).  It's the same as `io.sockets.emit()`.  Yes, socket.io doc is pretty weak.

Comment: @jfriend00  I revised my code structure

Comment: I used a mix between **socket.io** and Node.js **Events**. Check [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596689/using-socket-io-in-express-js-project/52103434#52103434).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will be needing `io` object to emit the event.

**Flow 1:** *passing io as global (quick fix)*

**app.js**

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
global.io = io; //added
require(./socket.js)(io)

app.listen(80)
```

**controller.js**

```
router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
 // I need to emit here
 global.io.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
});
```

**Notes:**
As far as passing the io object around. You have a few options, which may or may not be the best.

- Make io global. (altering global needs care)
- Use module.exports and require the object in the other files. (can lead to circular dependency issues if not done properly)

> Probably, the cleanest way is to pass is as arguments to the controllers, while requiring them in routes.

**Flow 2:** *passing io as arguments*

**app.js**

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

require(./router.js)(app,io);
require(./socket.js)(io);

app.listen(80);
```

**router.js**

```
/*
 * Contains the routing logic
 */
module.exports = function (app,io) {
//passing while creating the instance of controller for the first time.
var controller = require("./controller")(io);

app.get('/test/about',controller.myAction);
};
```

**controller.js**

```
module.exports = function(io){
    var that={};
    /*
     * Private local variable
     * made const so that 
     * one does not alter it by mistake
     * later on.
     */
    const _io = io; 

    that.myAction = function(req,res){

        _io.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
        res.send('Done');   
    }

    // everything attached to that will be exposed
    // more like making public member functions and properties.
    return that;
}
```

Comment: Let me try this  and let you know

Comment: @SivaSankar - It's considered a bad practice to use a global for this.  It wrecks the modularity of your code and creates an opportunity for name conflicts.  Better to pass it to the modules that need it.

Comment: yeah, you can that also. It's just a quick work around. But for name conflicts, one can always use. global._io = io sort of things.

Comment: Quick work-arounds end up in your code and then you have bad practices in your code.  Better to never put them there in the first place.

Comment: @ Nivesh & jfriend00. I tried before Socket Event with EventEmitter. I left bcz of bad pratice. Anyway I will try this one

Comment: Actually this is not bad for small projects and hackathon stuff. @jfriend00 if you could show more modular code to access `io` in controller rather than passing it to every controller then it would be helpful.

Comment: @SivaSankar any progress?

Comment: @Nivesh, No I am outside of office. Will Ping Exactly by 11AM IST

Comment: Global Working fine, As suggest going to pass arg in controllers

Comment: How can I include on controller ?

Comment: app.use('/provider', require('../controller/provider.js')(io)); This throwing an error

Comment: node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:140
var search = 1 + req.url.indexOf('?');
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Comment: see the new code flow added above. besides one should not do routing in controller, they are just meant for logic part.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you !!

Comment: I have used socket.io for realtime updates(whenever the food is ordered by customer the shop receives without reloading) but i have written emit in app.js my app works very slow even for 6-10 connection at a time. if i used the emit in particular controller whether the app runs normally?