# Exporting HTTP server for socket.io not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, httpserver

I have a `app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('./server.js');

// app.use
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   ...
});

module.exports = app;
```

And a `server.js`

```
const app = require('./app');
const server = app.listen(5000 || process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port 5000!');
})
module.exports = server;
```

If I put the server in a separated file the socket is not working, but if I start the server inside the `app.js` the socket works.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the two files are requiring each other and you are also not exporting the `io` instance

Comment: Why do I need to export the `io` instance? I'm trying to do some test like point 3 [here](http://www.albertgao.xyz/2017/05/24/how-to-test-expressjs-with-jest-and-supertest/). And I need the two files separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you have a circular dependency where `app.js` is loading `server.js` and `server.js` is loading `app.js`.  You can't do that for this type of code.

It has an issue because you're trying to load `server.js` from within `app.js` and then in the process of loading `server.js`, it attempts to load `app.js` and get its exports, but `app.js` hasn't finished loading yet and thus hasn't even returned its exports yet.  So, the loader either thinks there are no exports or recognizes the circular request (I'm not sure which), but in either case the exports from `app.js` don't work because of the circular requires.

There are several different ways to solve this.  The two most common ways are:

1. Break some code into a common third module that each of these can load and only have one of these load the other.
2. Rather than having `server.js` load `app` to get the `app` object, have `app.js` pass the `app` object to `server.js` in a constructor function rather than trying to execute at module load time.

Here's how the constructor function idea would work:

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// load server.js and call it's constructor, passing the app object
// that module constructor function will return the server object
const server = require('./server.js')(app);

// app.use
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   ...
});

module.exports = app;
```

server.js

```
// export constructor function that must be called to initialize this module
module.exports = function(app) {

    const server = app.listen(5000 || process.env.PORT, () => {
        console.log('App listening on port 5000!');
    });
    return server;
};
```

So, rather than `server.js` trying to load the `app.js` module to get the `app` object, the `app` object is "pushed" to it with a constructor function.  This prevents the circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain better _pass the app object to server.js in a constructor function rather than trying to execute at module load time._ or give me a link where is explained?

Comment: Yes thanks very clear, I'm trying if everything works before closing the question. Where can I learn more about this constructor technique? Is new to me.

Comment: @Mattia - It's really just exporting a function that can be called after the module is loaded.  It just allows you to pass some shared variables to the module initialization code which you move inside of this function.  The technique is often called a "module constructor", though it's really just exporting a function designed to be called right after loading the module.  I'm not aware of any particular reference on the topic.

Comment: @Mattia -  Here's one other answer on the topic: [Node.js - use of module.exports as a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511976/how-can-i-export-socket-io-into-other-modules-in-nodejs/38514118#38514118).

Comment: so is the module.exports exporting the object `server` and not the function?

Comment: @Mattia - The `server.js` exports are exporting a function.  That's all.  The line  `const server = require('./server.js')(app);` first does the `require('./server.js')`.  That gets the function that it exported.  Then, it calls that function with the `(app)` and calling that function returns the `server` object.  This could have been written on two separate lines to make it more obvious: `let startServer = require('./server.js');` followed by `let server = startServer(app)`.  But, I used a common shorthand to combine them into one line.

Comment: Now is clear. The server is working, thank you for the help