# Access socket emitter with socket.io in other modules nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'll preface this by saying I am new to nodejs in general. Coming from the world of C#, it's a completely different way of thinking for me.
I've gone through a few courses and I'm setting up a little website as sort of a test for myself. And I'm failing!

I'm using socket.io with node, and I'm trying to broadcast a message with the emitter once in a while. I don't care about specific socket points right now (although I will in the future), so the emitter for this should go out to everyone.

I am having trouble accessing the io object from other modules. 
I'll post my server.js file, as well as app/index.js, socket/index.js, helpers/index.js and api/index.js. I hope that posting these will show how it's supposed to work.

Ideally, I'd like to keep all socket-related items in the socket module, for consistency. Right now, I'm trying to get a method to run in the helpers module, but ideally the socket module would be better.

Anyway, server.js:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cryptometers = require('./app');
const api = require('./app/api');
const fs = require('fs');
const sources = require('./app/api/sources.json');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cryptometers.session);
app.use('/', cryptometers.router);

cryptometers.ioServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), () =>{
    console.log('app listening on port ' + app.get('port'));

api.getData(sources[0].source, sources[0].url, app);
setInterval(function(){api.getData(sources[0].source, sources[0].url, app)}, 60000);

});
```

Standard fare here. I just added a data retriever that calls to an api once every minute, which updates the database.

app/index.js:

```
'use strict';

const config = require('./config');

// create an IO server instance
let ioServer = app => {
    app.locals.globalMarketCap = [];

    const server = require('http').Server(app);
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);
    io.set('transports', ['websocket']);

    io.use((socket, next) => {
        require('./session')(socket.request, {}, next);
    });
    require('./socket')(io,app);
    return server;
}


// turns router into a module
module.exports = {
    router: require('./routes')(),
    session: require('./session'),
    ioServer,

}
```

Here I'm initializing socket.io, binding it to the app. It's also where I initialize a local storage array of data. (Is this a good spot to do this??)

socket/index.js:

```
'use strict';
const h = require('../helpers');

module.exports = (io, app) => {

    io.of('/').on('connection', socket =>{
        console.log('socket.io connected to client');

        if(app.locals.globalMarketCap){
            socket.emit('globalMarketCap', JSON.stringify(app.locals.globalMarketCap));
        }
    })
}
```

Here I'm responding to connection events, and pushing out the array of data that I defined in the last file above. Again, ideally I'd like all socket type stuff to stay in here.

helpers/index.js:

```
'use strict';
const router = require('express').Router();
const db = require('../db');

// iterate through the routes object and mount the routes
let _registerRoutes = (routes, method) => {
    for(let key in routes){
        if(typeof routes[key] === 'object' && routes[key] !== null && !(routes[key] instanceof Array)){
            _registerRoutes(routes[key], key);
        } else {
            // Register the routes
            if(method === 'get'){
                router.get(key, routes[key]);
            } else if(method === 'post'){
                router.post(key, routes[key]);
            } else {
                router.use(routes[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}

let route = routes => {
    _registerRoutes(routes);
    return router;
}

let updateGlobalMarketCap = (app) =>{
   //app.io.socket.emit('globalMarketCap', JSON.stringify(app.locals.globalMarketCap))
}

module.exports = {
    route,
    updateGlobalMarketCap
}
```

The commented out line for updateGlobalMarketCap is where my pain is. Trying to get access to the io object there.

api/index.js

```
'use strict';

const axios = require("axios");
const db = require("../db");
const h = require("../helpers");

let getData = (source, url, app, cryptoMeters) => {
    axios
        .get(url)
        .then(response => {
            //console.log(response.data);
            response.data["source"] = source;
            var data = new db.globalMarketCapModel(response.data);
            app.locals.globalMarketCap = response.data;
            var query = { source: source};

            db.globalMarketCapModel.findOne({
                "source":source
            }, 'source old_total_market_cap_usd total_market_cap_usd', function(err, market) {
                if (market) {
                    if(market.old_total_market_cap_usd != response.data.total_market_cap_usd
                    && market.total_market_cap_usd != response.data.total_market_cap_usd){
                        response.data["old_total_market_cap_usd"] = market.total_market_cap_usd;
                        h.updateGlobalMarketCap(app);
                    }

                    db.globalMarketCapModel.update(query, response.data, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("uhoh")
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    data.save(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("uhoh")
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    })
                }
            })

            return true;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return false;
        });
}


module.exports = {
    getData

}
```

The getData function here is where a call to the update emitter would take place.

I've considered using standard node event emitters as a solution to my problem, but that might be gumming up the works and there's a simpler answer.
Anyway, thanks for reading, and I'm interested in any commentary on what i've written so far. pitfalls, mistakes, etc. Learning here! :)

Comment: you need a ref to the object. you can pass it around, tack it on to/as a global, or wrap your module with something that enables persistence on future require()s by modifying the cache.

Comment: Here is the your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68167653/6482248

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to organize your code to accomplish sharing of the `io` object.  Here's one such scheme.  You break out your socket.io initialization code into its own module.  You give that module two main features:

1. A constructor function (that you pass the server to) that allows socket.io to initialize itself on your server.
2. A method to get the `io` instance after it's been initialized.

This will allow any other code in your project that wants to get access to the `io` object to do something like this:

```
const io = require('./io.js').getIO();
```

Here's how that `io` module could be structured:

```
// io.js

// singleton instance of socket.io that is stored here after the 
// constructor function is called
let ioInstance;

modules.exports = function(server) {
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);
    io.set('transports', ['websocket']);

    io.use((socket, next) => {
        require('./session')(socket.request, {}, next);
    });
    // save in higher scope so it can be obtained later
    ioInstance = io;
    return io;
}

// this getIO method is designed for subsequent 
// sharing of the io instance with other modules once the module has been initialized
// other modules can do: let io = require("./io.js").getIO();
module.exports.getIO = function() {
    if (!ioInstance) {
        throw new Error("Must call module constructor function before you can get the IO instance");
    }
    return ioInstance;
}
```

And, this module would be initialized like this:

```
const io = require('./io.js')(server);
```

Where you pass it your web server so it can hook to that.  It has to be initialized like this before anyone can use `.getIO()` on it.  The storage in the module of the `ioInstance` makes use of the module caching.  The module initialization code is only run once.  After that, the same exports are just returned each time which have access to the saved `ioInstance` inside the module.