# Share server from socket.io between files

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to be able to call io from other files. Point is that it doesn't update when a user is put into a room, or when `io.sockets` is called etc.

**server.js**

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/file.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/file.crt'),
  requestCert: false
};
var app = express();
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); io.origins('*:*');
global.io = io;

io.on('connection', function(socket) {  .. }
```

I've also tried;

```
module.exports.io
```

and then from the other file

```
require('server.js').io
```

This didn't work either,  I want to be running my server in one file which is the server js, I handle every incoming socket here etc. These are the two things I've tried but they both result in the same issue.

Comment: This is a general "how do I share data between modules question" and is not specific to socket.io at all.  That general question has been asked hundreds of times here.  Please search.  I will attempt to find one of the many dups.

Comment: @jfriend00 well yeah but exports wouldn't work right here

Comment: Uhhh, exports can work just fine.  globals are a bad idea as they are an enemy of modularization and testability (in other words, bad design).  There are hundreds of other questions/answers here and hundreds of web sites that show how you can use exports to share stuff between modules so there's no reason for us to provide a generic tutorial on that fact.  If you want help with how to make the exports work in your code, then file a new question, show exactly what you tried (both sides of the code, import and export) and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: @jfriend00 I need to wait 90 minutes lol

Comment: @jfriend00 I've google for an anwser for at least 2 hours and haven't found anything matching my issue, I found some where they just put everything in the module.exports but I want to handle everything in this file and I can't go change, I could but I'd rather not spend a week changing everything around, I would have to change at least 2000 lines. see updated anwser as it doesn't include much news but the only two things I tried that I thought might of been useful to what I've been wanting to achieve..

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I export socket.io into other modules in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511976/how-can-i-export-socket-io-into-other-modules-in-nodejs).

Comment: I've reopened your question and provided an answer specific to your issue.

Answer (score 7):

There are many different schemes for sharing a central variable (like your `io` variable) with other modules.  How exactly makes sense to do it depends upon an overall architecture, how you want your modules to be resuable, etc... but all use some combination of importing and exporting to share data between modules without using `global`.

In your specific case, you can do something very simple:

**server.js**

```
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/file.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/file.crt'),
  requestCert: false
};
const app = express();
const server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
const io = require('./socket.js').init(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {  .. }
```

**socket.js**

```
let io;
module.exports = {
    init: function(server) {
        // start socket.io server and cache io value
        io = require('socket.io').listen(server); io.origins('*:*');
        return io;
    }
    getio: function() {
        // return previously cached value
        if (!io) {
            throw new Error("must call .init(server) before you can call .getio()");
        }
        return io;
    }
}
```

**In other modules that want access to io**

```
const io = require('./socket.js').getio();
```

It should go without saying here that you have to call `.init(server)` before you can call `.getio()`.  This takes advantage of the node.js module caching system so that each time you call `require('./socket.js')` it is returning to you the same module that was first loaded and thus you have access to the previously cached `io` instance.

---

FYI, this is called a "pull" model where a module that wants access to something else uses a `require()` statement to "pull" in the variable it wants.

There is also a push module where the loader of the module pushes the data to the module by calling a function  in that module after it loads the module.

---

Here are some other ways to do it:

**Export from app.js**

You have to watch out for circular dependencies with this scheme because if app.js does `require('./a.js')` and then `a.js` does require('./app.js')`, you can create a circular dependency which will fail.  So, this model only works if`a.js`is doing a`require('./app.js')` after module load (like in a module constructor).

**app.js**

```
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/file.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/file.crt'),
  requestCert: false
};
const app = express();
const server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server); io.origins('*:*');


io.on('connection', function(socket) {  .. }

// exports some things we want to share
module.exports  = {
  io: io,
  app: app
};
```

**some other files that wants access to io**

```
 // module constructor
 modules.exports = function() {
     // can use io in here
     const io = require('./app.js').io;
}
```

---

**Push Model**

In this module, you pass the `io` variable to any other module that needs it when you load that other module.

**app.js**

```
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/file.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/file.crt'),
  requestCert: false
};
const app = express();
const server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server); io.origins('*:*');


io.on('connection', function(socket) {  .. }

// load someotherfile.js and pass it the io variable
require('./someotherfile.js')(io);
```

**some other files that wants access to io**

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    // put whatever code for your module here
    setInterval(function() {
        io.emit(...);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this when I get home, I don't need to change anything else in server.js file?

Comment: @VGOExclusive - Nothing else needs to change in server.js because `.init()` returns the `io` variable which you store locally there so you can use it just like you were.