# Access to Discord.Client instance from other modules

Tags: javascript, express, client, discord.js

I wonder if there is any way to access a `Discord.Client` instance from another file.

What I've tried:

**posts.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/checkRole', function (req, res) {
    const guild = client.guilds.find(guild => guild.id === '688678156374044803');
    let member = guild.members.get(req.body.id); // member ID
    // Here I get an error which says the 'guild' is undefined.
    res.send(response);
});

module.exports = router
```

**index.js**

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
global.client = new Discord.Client();
const express = require('express');

const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts')

app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/posts', postsRoute)

/*  ... some other code ... */

client.login(config.token);

app.listen(8080);

module.exports = { client }
```

I've also tried a similar approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511976/how-can-i-export-socket-io-into-other-modules-in-nodejs) but it didn't work either. Lastly I tried to store the client instance as a global variable but still no luck. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is not the fact that you can't properly export the client, but that the code that you want to use it with runs when the client is not ready yet: in fact, you're getting an error that says that no guild was found with the `.find` method, but it means that the client has the `.guilds` property and a `.find` method.
The client exists, the problem is that your code run before the `ready` event is fired: to avoid that, you can require your module inside the `ready` event handler. Here's an example:

```js
// index.js
client.on('ready', () => {
  const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts')

  let app = express()
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  app.use(express.json())
  app.use('/posts', postsRoute)

  app.listen(8080);
})
```

Comment: Now I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of null`

Comment: My bad, I didn't check for the guild itself, the problem is I was trying to create a member instance out of an undefined guild which is isn't exist...

Comment: Sooo everything solved? If that's the case please accept the answer so that the question is marked as resolved :)