# NodeJs + Socket.io : io.to from module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, socket.io, modularity

I'm trying to emit a message in a specific room in my modules following Patrick Robert's answer [How can i export socket.io into other modules in nodejs?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511976/how-can-i-export-socket-io-into-other-modules-in-nodejs)

io.js

```
var sio = require('socket.io');
var io = null;

exports.io = function () {
  return io;
};

exports.initialize = function(server) {
  return io = sio(server);
};
```

module.js

```
ioreq = require('./io')

ioreq.io().on('connection', function(socket) {
    var room_name = 2;
    socket.join(room_name);
    socket.to(room_name).emit("test",'This is a Test'); //This is working
});

function sendDataFromModule(data) { // This function don't do anything at all !
socket.to(room_name).emit("test",data);
}

sendDataFromModule('Test from function');// Not working

}
```

Can you help me make it work ?

Comment: Your second function doesn't work because `socket` is not defined within the scope of that function so you cannot use that variable.  You probably need to pass the socket into that or you need to switch to `io.to(...).emit(...)` depending upon what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make io global variable,
in io.js

```
 global.io = require("socket.io")(server);
```

in module.js

```
    //ioreq = require('./io') no need for this
    
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        var room_name = 2;
        socket.join(room_name);
        socket.to(room_name).emit("test",'This is a Test'); //This is working
    });
    function sendDataFromModule(data) {
io.in(room_name).emit("test",data); // change this
}

sendDataFromModule('Test from function');

}
```